# Kibana: Visualize only one entry

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack

Our application exposes various metrics through an MBean, these are pulled by logstash and saved to ElasticSearch. Typical metrics are "number_of_connected_users", connection status for external dependencies etc. I'd like to visualize this, but I can't see that Kibana supports displaying only the last query result, discarding the older ones.

I figure I need to either 1) Limit a query to return only one result and then visualize it, or 2) Have the query return multiple results and selecting the last one in a visualization. Anyone done this?

Answer (score 0):

[ Deleted old answer as your question makes more sense today! ]

Sadly, kibana doesn't support the idea of a "latest" record.

Here's [their issue](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/678) for it.